# Accessing state in parent class from a child class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I appreciate the previous assistance from this list.  Here is what I want to do.  A set of cascading classes that communicate with a server using get or post and receiving a response in JSON.  I have done this successfully in the past using HTML5, javascript and JQuery.  I would like new code to use React.  I've read a number of the articles documenting components, props and classes.  I don't quite get it yet.  I believe what I attempted is close but still wrong.  Babel gives me a syntax error.  See the failed code:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
                      constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                        this.state = {
                          value: ''
                        };
                        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
                        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
                      }

                      handleChange(event) {
                        const regexpr = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
                        if(event.target.value === '' || regexpr.test(event.target.value)){
                            this.setState({
                            value: event.target.value
                            });
                        }
                      }

                      handleSubmit(event) {
                        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
                        const {theName} = this.state.value;
                        return <NameProcess {"theName"}/>;  /* FAIL ! */
                      }

                      render() {
                        return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("form", {
                          onSubmit: this.handleSubmit
                        }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Name:", 
/*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
                          type: "text",
                          value: this.state.value,
                          onChange: this.handleChange
                        })), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
                          type: "submit",
                          value: "Submit"
                        }));
                  }
                }
```

NameProcess would be the name of the child class.  What am I doing wrong as a beginner?

Comment: Any reason you are not using JSX?

Comment: Hi @user639608 - Welcome to Stackoverflow. I believe awarrier99 has spotted the problem, but when asking such a question you should copy and paste the exact error that you are getting. Also, you say _"I appreciate the previous assistance from **this list**"_ — Stackoverflow isn't a "list" or a "forum" with threaded posts; it is a Q&A site, so less conversational; for example your opening that I quoted is generally discouraged — just ask what you're after as a question. See [ask] in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in the value to a specific prop that the child component, `NameProcess`, will look for. For example, `return <NameProcess value={theName} />;` and then access it in the child component through `this.props.value`. However, `const {theName} = this.state.value` will return `undefined` unless `value` is an object that has a property `theName`. You probably want to do `const { value } = this.state` instead.

But also, I'm not sure why you're returning this component from the `handleSubmit` function. What you could do instead, if you're trying to wait for submit until showing the component, is add this to your state to mark when a form is submitted:

`this.state = {
    value: '',
    submitted: false
};`

and to your `handleSubmit` function to update the value to `true`:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // to prevent default action taken on form submit
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
}
```

and to your render function to show the child component once submitted:

`{this.state.submitted && return <NameProcess value={this.state.theName} />}`

As @Yossi mentioned, you may want to clean up your `render` function using JSX, making your whole file, putting all of these suggestions together, something like this:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            submitted: false
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const regexpr = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
        if(event.target.value === '' || regexpr.test(event.target.value)){
            this.setState({
                value: event.target.value
            });
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { value } = this.state;
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + value);
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
    }

    render() {
        const { value, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            {submitted ? <NameProcess value={value} /> : (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            )}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {  /*1*/
                      constructor(props) { /*2*/
                        super(props);
                        this.state = { /*3*/
                          value: '',
                          submitted: false
                        }; /*3*/
                        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
                        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
                      } /*2*/

                      handleChange(event) { /*2 */
                        const regexpr = /^[0-9\b]+$/;

                        if (event.target.value === '' || 
regexpr.test(event.target.value)) { /* 3 */
                          this.setState({ /* 4 */
                            value: event.target.value
                          }); /* 4 */
                        } /* 3 */
                      } /* 2 */

                      handleSubmit(event) { /* 2 */
                        event.preventDefault();
                        const { /* 3 */
                          value
                        } = this.state; /* 3 */
                        alert('A name was submitted: ' + value);
                        this.setState({ /* 3 */
                          submitted: true
                        }); /* 3 */
                      } /* 2 */

                      render() { /* 2 */
                                return this.state.submitted ? 
/*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(NameProcess, { /* 3 */
                                  value: this.state.value
                                }) : 
                                     /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("form", { /* 3 */ /* 3 */ 
                                       onSubmit: this.handleSubmit
                                }, 
                                /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Name:"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", { /* 3 */ /* 3 */ 
                                  type: "text",
                                  value: this.state.value,
                                  onChange: this.handleChange
                                }), 
                                /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", { /* 3 */ /* 3 */ 
                                  type: "submit",
                                  value: "Submit"
                                })); /* 3 */ 

                              } /* 2 */
                      } /* 1 */

                      class NameProcess extends React.Component {  /*1*/
                          constructor(props) { /*2*/
                            super(props);
                          } /*2*/
                          render(){ /* 2 */
                                  return 'blah!';
                              }  /* 2 */
                      } /* 1 */
```